# Microsoft office assistant

Tags: c#, winforms

Do you remember this cute little one?

[image]

I need something like this to add it to my project, in order to give user some instructions. I have like step by step procedure and I need to give user "To do" hints, do you know any library that offers me such a thing?

Comment: FYI: A lot of people *hated* Clippy, myself included

Comment: I like it, do you have any useful suggestions? :)

Comment: My immediate reaction was "You've got to be kidding -- somebody actually *wants* that thing?" My second reaction is, if you insist on inflicting this on your users, at least make it *really* easy to turn off (and no, I don't know of anything to help you do this).

Comment: "It looks like you are trying to annoy your users. Would you like help?"

Comment: When users are confused and irritated because they cannot figure out how to use their computer, the *last* thing they want is getting reminded that their abilities compare unfavorably to a figure that has a brain the size of a paper clip, the sanitary habits of a search dog or the social graces of somebody called Bob.

Comment: http://xenon.stanford.edu/~lswartz/paperclip/

Answer (score 2):

With older versions of Office when you installed the assistants you would also get the ability to use those assistants via COM. [Here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/12/02/PowerShell-_2D00_-Ask-Merlin_3A00_-a-cool-demo-of-using-COM-objects.aspx) is an example for PowerShell.

However, this won't work anymore with Office 2007 or 2010.

Comment: Microsoft also eventually spun the technology off as Microsoft Agent... and then killed it when it became clear the only real user of the library was BonziBuddy.

Comment: Which library? you said "the only real user of the library was BonziBuddy"??

Comment: @Shaza: Microsoft Agent, as Chris stated. It's no longer available, though and doesn't work on current Windows versions.

Comment: @ Johannes: if I get that COM component from office 97, would I be able to add it to my project, I'm using Win7 and VS2008.I mean without that library, can I use it?